# Supplementary Motor Area or Juxtapositional Lobule Cortex

Tags: neuroscience, neuroimaging, brain, neuroanatomy

Harvard-Oxford Cortical Structural Atlas now calls the 'Supplementary Motor Area' the 'Juxtapositional Lobule Cortex (formerly Supplementary Motor Cortex)'. I've looked for papers that explain the name change but haven't managed to locate any. All the papers I've found either continue to use SMA or give both ('JLC formerly SMC') without explanation. Where did this change originate? Is JLC the accepted term now?

Comment: I am interested in this too.  I saw that you posted the question on Reddit.  If you find anything based on the comments you received there, you can always self-answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. I will.